# sprang up VS be springing up

Tags: grammar, phrases

I found two example sentences recently about “spring up” in Collins and Oxford dictionaries.

> New theatres and arts centres sprang up all over the country.

> New houses were springing up all over the town.

I don't understand why the second sentence uses the past progressive tense. Is there any difference in emphasis in this sentence compared to the first one?

Comment: Obviously both were continuing processes - the theatres and arts centres didn't all open on the same day - but the continuous (progressive) tense emphasises that the building of new houses was happening repeatedly.

Comment: Do you understand the normal difference between *simple past* and *past progressive*?